# Selenium + FF : How to fix error, Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, testcase

My script is not running even by using selenium 2.53.1 and firefox 47.0.1. `Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.` is the error returned.

The script that was tried is,

```
package SystemPackTest; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 
public class TestCalass { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        WebDriver driver ;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<geckodriver path>");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.get("google.com"); 
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website"); 
        //driver.close(); 
    } 
}
```

Question - How to fix error, Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms?

Comment: Can you share your script?

Comment: package SystemPackTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class TestCalass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  
       
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
 
   
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website");
 

  
        //driver.close();
 }
}

Comment: @Nazish, for opening url we need to give link with http:// also.              
// Go to URL
`driver.get("https://www.google.com");`
And selenium 2.53.1 is not compatible for Firefox 47.0.1. (I think this two will resolve your problem)

Comment: Latest Firefox may have now fixed this issue, please retest against latest firefox version

Comment: Pls accept most helpful answer, So this question will not be in Active state for long

Comment: I tried the same. I am using Selenium 3 and firefox version 52 but still getting the same error. I am using gecko version 1.15.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1 -**

I will suggest to downgrade (replace with older version) your ff browser version. You are unable to connect to 127.0.0.1 maybe because version do not support each other.

**Upgrade or downgrade version for Selenium or FF will resolve issue.**

Note - Prefer to downgrade FF version, I got success with such approach.

**Solution 2 -**
Try running this before you start your Selenium server:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

*DISPLAY* is essentially an environment variable which needs to be exported from the command line.

Comment: still got the same issue even after degrade FF to 40.0

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
this error occur

Comment: Understood FF Version 40.0 is also having error. Can you further degrade and try to install 38.6.0? I am using FF version 38.6.0 & Its working well with selenium 2.47.1

Comment: Download FF version to 38.0.6, it worked

Comment: Faced the same issue. Downgraded FF to 41.0 and it worked fine!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Scenarios :**

1. **As per [Selenium Webdriver 3.0 Documentation](http://seleniumsimplified.com/2016/07/first-impressions-of-selenium-webdriver-3-0-0-beta-1/) and [Geckodriver Configuration Document](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3),**

   > Selenium 3.0 and higher version require Java8 and Firefox 46,47+ versions.

***Note : Here you require to use geckodriver***

2. **For Selenium Webdriver 2.53.1 and Lesser version,**

   > Require lesser version from Firefox 45 and Java7

***Note : Here only `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` will work perfectly.***

**Please configure system as per above combination and verify your script.**

As per given comments, **Answer is scenario 2.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case just now the issue was that I was passing a prepared profile dir that obviously appeared absent/invalid when I switched from MacOS to Windows node.

Yeah, it was impossible to figure this out by just reading the node/hub stderr.